# Raspberry Pi cannot allocate memory for libcamera image

Tags: raspicam

Good morning,
I am having some difficulties with the Raspberry Pi camera v2.1 I just received. My Raspberry Pi is a Pi 3 Model B v1.2. I am getting this error:
`Unable to request 3 buffers: Cannot allocate memory`

Here is my boot.txt file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1
#start_x=1
gpu_mem=128

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]

####################################################
####     MainsailOS specific configurations     ####
####################################################
####      DO NOT CHANGE SECTION BELOW !!!       ####
####   UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING !!!   ####
####################################################

## For more options and information see
## https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html
## Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

## For additional information about device filters see
## https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#model-filters


[pi0]
## This affects Pi Zero(W) and Pi Zero2
## Due lag of RAM, limit GPU RAM
gpu_mem=128

[pi2]
gpu_mem=128

[pi3]
## Use 256 if 1Gb Ram Model!
gpu_mem=128
# gpu_mem=256

[pi4]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
## Do not use more than 256Mb on Pi Model 4, it uses its own Management.
gpu_mem=256

[all]

## SPI Interface is enabled by default for Input Shaper
## This colides with Hyperpixel Display!
## Hyperpixel Screen uses the same Pin for Backlight.
dtparam=spi=on

gpu_mem=256

## Enable Hardware UART for Serial Communication
## This also disables Bluetooth!
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=disable-bt


## Disable libcamera (interferes with ustreamer, when using raspicams)
start_x=1

## Enable VideoCore at boot, needed for Crowsnest (Raspicams and DSI devices).
start_x=1


### EXPERIMENTAL - Enable 64bit Kernel
### The 64-bit kernel will only work on:
### Raspberry Pi 3, 3+, 4, 400, Zero 2 W and 2B rev 1.2
### and Raspberry Pi Compute Modules 3, 3+ and 4.
# arm_64bit=1

####################################################

[all]
```

And this is the output of the "free" command:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          751596      133212      134752         936      483632      552948
Swap:         262140           0      262140
```

Comment: try adding `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` into the pi3 section (I've read that can help)

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX it worked!